# JSR223 assertion on JDBC update request in Jmeter

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, assertion

I have JDBC request which updating some value in database. For this request, I have two child assertions one `response` and one `JSR223` to check response code and updated value respectively . But I get a failed request (red)  in view results tree as I think JSR223 is asserting value before it is updated.  When I check database manually , value is being updated.

I was assuming that by putting response assertion before JSR223 assertion , it would be fine as JSR223 will assert when request has been fully executed.

When I disable JSR223, I get response assertion passed and hence green request in result tree.

How do I assert on the value updated by the JDBC request in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

1. As per [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder): assertions are being executed after Samplers so JDBC Request sampler is "fully" executed and only after that Assertions are being executed.
2. Assertions are being executed upside down
3. If any of assertions fails - the Sampler will be marked as failed
4. Specific for the JSR223 Assertions: if you made a mistake and the code won't compile - the assertion will fail and fail the relevant Sampler. See [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more details if needed.

So double check your assertion code and inspect:

1. [Assertion Results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Assertion_Results) listener output
2. [JMeter Log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Comment: Thanks for the info . Actually the issue was that , update assertion was checking  against a select JDBC request that was written at the start of the test plan . Didn't realize that I need to  again send a  select JDBC request and not utilize the previous request.